# Is there any way to hook Crowd with Wordpress? Other way to do external authentication?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I saw this old connector but is deprecated: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWDEXT/WordPress+Connector

Is there other any way to use Crowd authentication for WordPress?

If this is not a good option to do an authentication, is there another way to **do external authentication or use the WordPress login to login in other or external websites?**

Comment: Does [WordPress SSO](http://jetpack.me/support/sso/) help?

Comment: It's possible but I prefer use my personal WordPress user account control. I want to use for WP and for another site outside this.

Comment: is the "other" site reside in same web server ?

Comment: It's the idea. Possible with LDAP? Is it a good option?

Comment: Given that the pages are in same web server, you can use your own WordPress credentials in other pages outside WordPress root. See [this discussion](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/check-for-login-outside-wordpress)

Comment: It seems good option but complicated to apply. Thanks

Comment: Development is never an easy task. Please understand.